# Scrolling sidebar throws Javascript error "Cannot call method 'offset' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Essentially I'm working on a sidebar that only scrolls once the browser window has reached it.

UPDATE 2:

This is the code I'm currently working with:

```
$(function() {
var $sidebar   = $("#sidebar"),
    $window    = $(window),
    offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
    topPadding = 15;

    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            $sidebar.addClass('fixed');
        } else {
            $sidebar.removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
});
```

I am no longer getting the error, however the sliding does not work. This fiddle here shows the desired effect, and my CSS is exactly the same: http://jsfiddle.net/dKDJz/647/

Comment: Do you have jQuery's `.js` file loaded?

Comment: In js fiddle it wraps your code in dom ready by default, have you tried wrapping your code ina document ready ?

Comment: @Sergio Yes I do, I've run a console.log to test and var $sidebar is set.

Comment: WHat does the console show to `console.log($sidebar);`

Comment: @Sergio it returns as null

Comment: I suspected that. I think your problem is one of the two I described in my answer. Check them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this code works in your the fiddle you might to want to **check 2 things**:

- **wrap your code in ready function**

It might be that your code is running before the element exists/renders. In that case wrapp your code with a [**ready**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function

```
$(function() {
  // your code
});
```

- **check that you are loading the jQuery library files.**

In case you didn't load the jQuery library files, add this inside the  tag in your page.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did both of these suggestions and it still doesn't work however there are no errors now.

Comment: Do you have a live link? If `console.log($sidebar);` loggs as NULL then jQuery is not loading, otherwise you would have a jQuery object anyway, not NULL. Also from other comments you wrote about another error "has no method 'ready'". Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Unfortunately this site is not live, but I can probably get an example up soon. As I console.log($sidebar); now, it shows nothing in the console. I'm using exactly what you typed above for jquery.

Comment: @user2766423, do you have another framework also besides jQuery? is it a wordpress site?

Comment: After doing some digging, it looks like prototype.js was installed on the same page and for whatever reason it was causing the div not to slide. Everything works when prototype.js is not included.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your selector in a doc ready wrapper.
Essentially #sidebar isn't available when your trying to run the selector.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    var $sidebar   = $("#sidebar"),
    $window    = $(window),
    offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
    topPadding = 15;

    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            $sidebar.addClass('fixed');
        } else {
            $sidebar.removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried this and realized I'm getting a different error, "Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready'.

Answer (score 1):

```
var topPadding = 15;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    //alert($(window).scrollTop())
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $("#sidebar").offset().top) {
        $("#sidebar").addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $("#sidebar").removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```